# How can I pass data from a low level component to global state with useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component NewForm.js where I collect data from a form and I want that data to render later in a list somewhere else, I can do component drilling lift the state to App.js but it sucks and I know there is a way i can do that with useContext and useReducer, I know how to send data from a global state down the component but I don't know how to "lift the state up" from NewForm.js to global state

Answer (score 0):

In parent component you should to create a context with setFunction and result. Then pass this values to context provider. And you can use this in your consumer component
For example

```js
const [state, setState] = useState()

<Context.Provider value={{State, setState}}>
```

And your useContext will return "setState" and "state". When you call "setState" your consumer and other child components will be render